# MVC 4 Session Variable getting updated and I don't know how

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method to retrieve session variables, in this case Organizations.  For some reason, when I call the get session method the get Organizations and pass the data to a SelectList method to handle some naming logic, the session variable is getting updated.  I don't wanted the session values updated and don't understanding what is happening. Below are all the methods.  What am I missing?

**Controller Method:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            SignUpEventFormModel model = new SignUpEventFormModel();

            SelectListHelpers listHelper = new SelectListHelpers();
            model.OrganizationList = listHelper.GetOrgSelectList(sessionRepository.GetUserSession().Organizations, null);

            return View(model);
        }
```

**Get User Session Method:**

```
 public UserSession GetUserSession()
        {
            UserSession us =  (UserSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserSession"];
            if (us == null)
            {
                string email = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                SessionSetupRepository sessionsetupRepository = new SessionSetupRepository(new UserRepository(null, null), new SignUpRepository(), new ActivityRepository(), new OrganizationRepository());
                us = sessionsetupRepository.SetupUserSession(email);
            }

            return us;
        }
```

**Get Org Select List Method:**

```
   public SelectList GetOrgSelectList(IEnumerable<Organization> Orgs, int? SelectedOrgID)
        {
            List<Organization> OrgList = Orgs.ToList();

            OrgList.Where(o => !o.IsAdmin).ToList().ForEach(o => o.Name = o.Name + " (Permission Request Required)");

            if (SelectedOrgID.HasValue)
                return new SelectList(OrgList, "OrganizationID", "Name", (int)SelectedOrgID);
            else
                return new SelectList(OrgList, "OrganizationID", "Name");
        }
```

Comment: That's how reference types work in .NET. Contrary to value types you are passing references and not values. Thus their name: reference types.

Comment: How to get just the values and not pass the reference?  Note, I am using Ninject to inject the Session Repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a IList parameter and converted the organizations to a list.